# Open graph / og: meta tags Facebook Messenger

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph, facebook-messenger

Looking for a best practice solution.
I currently have metatags in my script to show Open Graph metadata  when forwarding links from the webpage.

All icons are 112x112 ie square and these come out v well on WhatsApp etc.
They also come out well on Facebook when inputted into the NewsFeed.

However - if i try and forward that feed via Facebook Messenger - the image is of different dimensions and seems like i need a higher resolution.

What script adjustments would one need to accomodate for this? I don't want to have to redefine, or add newer images.

Thanks